# Editing and Deleting List<> Items from ListView Box - C#

Tags: c#, winforms, list, data-structures

I have reached a problem in my program, and that is editing and deleting my tasks after I have entered them.

When I enter a task, I then click on my displayTask button which does this:

```
//Used to display the tasks onto the listview
        for (int i = 0; i < taskStructure.TasksArray.Count ; i++)
        {
            displayTaskLvb.Items.Add((i + 1).ToString()); //This would be the taskIDColumn to signify what task member it is! It increments by one for each new task added 
            displayTaskLvb.Items[i].SubItems.Add(taskStructure.TasksArray[i].taskName); //Enter the task name from the list
            displayTaskLvb.Items[i].SubItems.Add(taskStructure.TasksArray[i].taskDescription); //Enter the task description
            displayTaskLvb.Items[i].SubItems.Add(taskStructure.TasksArray[i].taskPriority.ToString()); //Enter the task name from the list
            displayTaskLvb.Items[i].SubItems.Add(taskStructure.TasksArray[i].taskDateAndTimeCompletion); //Enter the task description
        }
```

Which works great and everything is in the right column on my ListViewBox. My problem is how do I edit the tasks a user enters? It is saved to my list which is this:

```
public static List<taskStructure> TasksArray = new List<taskStructure>(); //Declared a list data structure to hold the tasks
```

I want to be able to click on the task in my listViewBox and then edit the Name, Description etc. of that task, whether that will be on the listBox or a form, which will then update my List<>. Methods have been tried to access which task they click on, but I can't get anything to work. The same with deleting a task, how can I delete the task that the user clicks on in my ListViewBox?

Any help can be greatly appreciated, I would post a picture to help but I do not have enough rep.

Kind Regards,

Kieran Lowe

Comment: If you want to be able to edit any single column then you should use a DataGridView not a ListView. In alternative you should open a form where editing occurs in separate textboxes

Comment: @Steve Okay, I have just changed it but now I'm unsure how to add the variable contents to the data view locations. e.g. as dataGridView does not contain methods for .Items() etc.

Comment: Create a BindingSource object, set its DataSource to your List<TaskArray> and then set the DataSource of the DataGridView to the BindingSource instance. You should be able to find thousands of examples on setting the DataSource of a DataGridView and how to customize the DataGridView editing process.